# How to sample from smaller data frame with multiple conditions to a larger data frame?

Tags: r, random, dplyr, sampling

I have a main dataset `df.main` with 3 sites and each site has 3 subsites, that were samlpled over three months. I have a separate dataset with some abiotic variables ONLY for a single month `df.sample`. But for each site, I have three values from the sub-sites. In my original dataset, I need to add the `abitoic` column. However, for every month, for each sub-site I only want to **SAMPLE** with replacement from one of the three samples from the sub.site.

```
set.seed(111)

##Main Data Set
month <- rep(c("Jan","Feb","Mar"), each =9 )
site <- rep(c("1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3"), each = 3)
sub.site <- rep(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), time = 3 )

df.main <- data.frame(month, site, sub.site)
  month site sub.site
Jan    1        1
Jan    1        2
Jan    1        3
Jan    2        1
Jan    2        2
...     ..      ..
Mar    3        3

##Sampler Data Set
site <- rep(c(1,2,3), time = 9)
sub.site <- rep(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), each = 3)
abiotic <- rnorm(27,7,1)
df.sample <- data.frame(site, sub.site, abiotic)

  site sub.site  abiotic
 1        1      7.175096
 1        1      8.805868
 1        1      6.783571
 1        2      7.910917
 1        2      7.202307
 1        2      8.404883
 ...
 2        1      7.122915
 2        1      6.152732
 ...
 3        1      7.978232
 3        1      6.870228

##Desired Output in df.main
month site sub.site abiotic
  Jan  1     1      8.805868
  Jan  1     2      7.910917
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a full join of the two tables using `site` and `sub.site`, and then just sample one row from each `month`, `site` and `sub.site` combination.

If you are unsure about table joining (full join, left join, etc.), you may want to look that up online. It is very simple and standard in, say querying database.

In your case, after the full joining, because you have 9 unique combination of `site` and `sub.site`, you will have 81 rows:

```
joining.output <- df.main %>%
  full_join(df.sample, by = c("site", "sub.site"))

> joining.output
   month site sub.site  abiotic
1    Jan    1        1 7.235221
2    Jan    1        1 4.697654
3    Jan    1        1 5.502573
...
28   Feb    1        1 7.235221
29   Feb    1        1 4.697654
30   Feb    1        1 5.502573
...
55   Mar    1        1 7.235221
56   Mar    1        1 4.697654
57   Mar    1        1 5.502573
```

Then to sample 1 row for each `site` and `sub.site` combination for each `month`, just group by the 3 variables and sample.

Here is the code that puts everything together:

```
output <-  df.main %>%
  full_join(df.sample, by = c("site", "sub.site")) %>%
  group_by(month, site, sub.site) %>%
  slice_sample(n=1)
```

p.s. in your example, `df.main$sub.site` is a character array but `df.sample$sub.site` is a numeric array. You may want to convert the character array to numeric using `as.double()` function before joining.